# I cant compile simple project with CMake and CLion

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw32

I never had this problem before. I havent change anything, but basic project template doesnt work now.
Here is my log:

```
CMake Error at C:/_programs/CLion 2019.2.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):  
The C compiler

"C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/_git/working-stuff/c++/untitled/cmake-build-debug-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-W/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_bdbcf/fast && C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-W/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_bdbcf.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/_git/working-stuff/c++/untitled/cmake-build-debug-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_bdbcf.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~2.0-W\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\_git\working-stuff\c++\untitled\cmake-build-debug-mingw\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_bdbcf.exe
"C:\_programs\CLion 2019.2.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\_programs\CLion 2019.2.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir/objects.a
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~2.0-W\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~2.0-W\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe      -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o cmTC_bdbcf.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_bdbcf.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir\linklibs.rsp
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find @C:\Windows\Temp\ccEffRpy: Invalid argument
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_bdbcf.dir\build.make:88: cmTC_bdbcf.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/_git/working-stuff/c++/untitled/cmake-build-debug-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: cmTC_bdbcf/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

My configuration:
[image: configuration]

Comment: Have you tried deleting your CMake cache and build folder and running from scratch?

Comment: @squareskittles since log show detection of C compiler failed, this is fresh/first run of cmake, so there is no CMakeCache yet. Problem must be some environment configuration. Reinstall of CLion/MinGW may help.

Comment: i deleted cache and reinstalled mingw. reinstalling the whole ide is really the only option for this?

Comment: Does MInGW work for compiling a simple executable when you simply use it from the command line (without CLion)? And no, reinstalling the IDE should not be necessary.

Comment: @squareskittles yes, g++ from mingw works perfectly fine. i didnt test MAKE tho.